# selenium webdriver: clicking images on page with Css selector

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have search button so when I type ABC, I get 4 images and I have to click first image. So I have written the code

```
WebElement Search = driver.findElement(By.id("SimpleSearchForm_SearchTerm"));
Search.sendKeys("ABC");
List<WebElement>listImg=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("id.searchDropdown"))
listImg.get(0).click();
```

while debugging I see listImg is having only 1 value

modcount   1
size       1

and when I click `listImg.get(0).click();` 
its clicking on 2nd image and when I mention `listImg.get(1).click();`

I get indexArrayoutofbounds Exception.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Post the HTML content of the page. Either there is only image OR your CSS selector is incorrect OR you are trying to access the web elements before they are loaded. Try adding a wait after searching.

Comment: Shouldn't need a wait because clicking the first element is working... sounds like, as you said, the CSS selector isn't optimal.

Comment: I included wait function until all 4 images are displayed. There are 4 images.

Comment: List<WebElement>listImg=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div#suggestedProductsResults")       HTML content  <divid="suggestedProductsResults">
<ul class="search-results__items part">    
<li class="heading">
<h4>
<span>  </h4></li><li><a title=ABC" class> <img alt="image ABC" </a></li><li><a title=ABC1" class> <img alt="image ABC1" </a> <li><a title=ABC2" class> <img alt="image ABC2" </a><li><a title=ABC3" class> <img alt="image ABC3" </a>